# joomla front page

Tags: joomla

Hii

i am trying hard to edit my joomla front page. I wanted it to be just a blog kind of page as of now. So I unpublished all the modules to make it empty first. Then i went to the home menu and edited its type to category blog layout and selected appropriate category.

but still there is no change in the front page. pLease help me out.

Comment: Did you check the category and make sure it contain contents first? Are you listing a (front page->blog layout) instead of (category->blog layout) ?

Comment: Is you home menu is a default menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your default home type is front page blog layout. You can change the your blog layout using parameters basics.

If you want to show your blog based on your category try to change your blog type to category blog layout instead of front page blog layout.